# Failing "if" in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this piece of code that doesn't seem to work for a strange reason:

```
    <% if (@user.photo.blank?) %>               
        <%= image_tag("empty_profile_pic.png") %> <!-- replace with user's image -->
    <%else %>
        <%= image_tag(@user.photo.url(:small)) %> 
    <% end %>
```

If the picture is null in the mySQL database I want it to display another pic.
I have tried, `empty?, nil?, blank?` but with no success, and also

```
 @user.photo.blank.url.*
```

Any help?

Comment: What plugin do you use for image-handling? Carrierwave? Dragonfly? Paperclip?

Answer (score 1):

How about

@user.photo.exists?

~Charles~

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= image_tag(@user.photo.try(:url, :small) || "empty_profile_pic.png") %>
```